# Importing template in MikTeX

Tags: miktex, texworks

I am using the Miktex to write my thesis. Can I import the template in the Miktex to follow that format?

[image]

I would like to upload the latex file (Zip file) with already having the certain format. But in Miktex console, I cannot see any option to upload the latex file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: miktex (unlike Overleaf) is tex installed _on your machine_. So you do not upload anything or need to zip the sources, simply run latex in whatever folder you wrote the file.

Comment: So while using the Miktex, I do not need to import any packages like we do in Overleaf..right?

Comment: you probably have the packages already or (normally) miktex will install thm when needed automatically. Or you can force install using the miktex console (not the texworks editor you show in your image)